# Access to XMLHttpRequest at https://login.microsoftonline.com has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET web app which calls an API to get some data from an ASP.NET Core web app of mine. This worked fine until I added Microsoft sign-in to the ASP.NET Core app. I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp) Microsoft Documentation exactly step-by-step to add the sign-in. The sign-in works perfectly; however, this has caused an issue with the API. Now when the API call is made, I get this error in the console (with the sensitive info replaced by {...}):

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at
'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri=
{redirect_uri}&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce={nonce}&client_info=
1&x-client-brkrver=IDWeb.1.11.0.0&state={state}&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=6.10.2.0'
(redirected from {redirect_uri}) from origin {origin} has been blocked by CORS policy:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I'm certain this issue isn't caused by either of my 2 apps since sending/receiving the data worked prior to adding the sign-in. I've tried looking through the Azure Portal to see if there are any changes that could be made there to fix this issue, but I haven't yet found anything there. What could be causing this issue? Is there anything specific which must be done in the Portal? Does there seem any issue with the super long https://login.microsoftonline.com... URL is it supposed to be that way?

Comment: Hi, it seems that your asp.net core app plays the role of api server, and asp.net web app works like an 'front-end' program. So I think the scheme for your solution to integrate azure ad should be that adding login module in your asp.net web app and add authentication module in your asp.net core app. In other words, you should follow [this tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-webapp) to enable sign-in and [this one](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis) for your api.

Comment: And [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-overview) for enable web api protection for your asp.net core app.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Tiny Wang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15581227/tiny-wang). Posting your suggestions as an answer to help other community members.

Integrate Azure AD to your [asp.net web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-webapp) and [asp.net core app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis)

here is the image on how the sample app works

[image]

You need to register your web api and expose it through scopes which will help in providing permission based access.

[image]

When you click on [Add Scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis#add-a-scope), it will prompt for application id uri
if you haven't set you need to set one

`api://<application-client-id>`  default applicationid uri

[check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-overview) this to enable protection to your Web API